# How to set current object (Me) to a new object stored in an array in Visual Basic for Excel

Tags: vba, object, excel

I have an array of objects in an excel vba project. I have created another instance of the same class and set 1 of its properties.  I am then trying to search through the array of objects to find the object in the array that matches the current one on the same property.  I would like to set the current object to the one in the array inside one of the current object's methods using the self reference Me.

I tried:

```
Set Me = objectArray(index)
```

This does not work.  It says that this is an improper use of the Me keyword.  Is there a way to set the current object to another object of the same type?  Thanks!

Edit:

I have an object that has child objects:

```
Me.friShift.shiftType.loadFromArray
```

Here, shiftType is the object of type CVocabulary, which is my self defined class.  It has a sub called loadFromArray that looks like this:

```
Public Sub loadFromArray()

    Dim index As Integer

    index = searchVocabArray(Me.typed)

    If (index = -1) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set Me = vocabArray(index)

End Sub
```

vocabArray() is a global array containing CVocabulary objects.

If it is not possible to Set an object from within itself, I can try something else.  This is just the easiest and most direct way of doing this.  I'm sure I can just set each parameter from the current object to the value of the parameter from the object in the array, but if it was possible to do something like the above, that would have been my preferred method.

Comment: It would help to show more relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by giving itself to the function as a parameter. I'll show it in VBScript because the classes are more clear, but the concept is the same as in VBA:

```
public myObject
set myObject = new x
myObject.ChangeMe MyObject
msgbox typename(myObject)    ' <-  outputs 'y'


class x
    public sub changeMe(byref object)
        set object = new y
    end sub
end class

class y
   ' just an empty class
end class
```

But this is not a good programming pattern and could cause messy code (maintenance and debugging would be an issue) and even memory leaks. You should create an `(Abstract) Factory`, `Builder` or `Provider` that returns an object as you ask for it.

- [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern): creates a new predefined object
- [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern): creates a new object that is configured in the builder
- [Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972319.aspx): returns an existing object that is predefined earlier

Answer (score 1):

I don't beleive you can use Me in this context - you are trying to use Me as it was used in VB6 (which was equivalent to 'this' in C#).  This is not appropriate in VBA.

Without some code snippets its hard to see what you are doing.  Can you perform the search in a module and create instances of this class there?  You can then do:

```
Set class2 = objectArrayofClass1(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've already seen that Me cannot be changed. You can handle memorized objects through 
a function in a public Module like basExternal:

```
Public Function loadFromArrayByIndex(ByVal lIndex)
  dim xobj as Object

  Set xobj = vocabArray(lIndex)

  '
  ' do modifications and handling on this object:
  ' ...
  '

End Function
```

.